# How to send automatic newsletter in Rails using MailChimp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mailchimp

Is there a way I can send content of a newsletter to MailChimp from a Rails app and have it send it out to the list?

Maybe a mailchimp gem that provides this integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Hominid Gym found here- https://github.com/terra-firma/hominid to connect to the MailChimp API. from there you could use the mailchimp methods to create campaign content, etc.

Comment: this gem seems not available or the address got changed.